Включение Intel VT-X
Мне понадобилось установить виртуалку, и когда я ее запускаю, то вылазит ошибка что у меня выключена интеловская виртуализация. я посмотрел на сайте, у меня стоит процессор I3-3240, и он поддерживают VT-X, но почему то у меня в биосе нету, хоть и процессор поддерживает. Пробовал отключить Hyper-V, но не помогло. Думаю, возможно биос старый? Моноблок DNS Extreme ALH236SB2
